# What, if anything, does it tell me when my application freezes, but my database is operational

Tags: php, mysql, performance, report, totara

So i am currently tasked with tuning the performance of a rather large report, generated by my application.

I wager I will have to solve this with using a materialized view, but that is not entirely the point. I observed something curious, I realized I did not understand, so I thought I would ask here.

When I tell my application to create the report, I can prefilter the data. For smaller datasubsets (Like only last 30 days) it works, but a bit slower than expected. When I run the report on all of my data (which I eventually want to do), the application stays at "connecting..." in the browser. I have never been able to get the full report to work, but I have never tried for longer than a couple of hours.

However, when I just realized that I did all my tuning work and whatever on my database, while the report was trying to run in my application. I did not notice ANY slowdown in the database, and I can perfectly work with the data.

So at this point I probably dont understand databases as well as I would like. Can they run multiple queries at once? Because in my naive understanding I am wondering, whether the database should not freeze as well if the application is running a large query on it.

I am using mysql 5.5.

Comment: Yes, a server can handle multiple http and database requests simultaneously. You should measure what takes how long to see where the problem is and post relevant code of that part to get detailed help.

Comment: To discuss speeding up "the performance of a rather larger report", please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the `SELECT`.

Comment: I have done so here (since it is another question imo): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44921100/optimizing-complicated-query-for-report-generation